# How to pass List<sObject> to @InvocableMethod that accepts only @InvocableVariable

Tags: apex, invocable-method, invocablevariable

I have a @InvocableMethod that is used from Flow builder to create a record.

Also I have a inner class with @invocableVariable.

It is working fine, but I want to use the same method to create records from another method that the parameter is differente, in this case I would like to pass List of Case, for example.

```
public class XPTO{
   @InvocableMethod(label='XPTU')
   public static List<Id> createRecord(List<Inner> inner){
       for(Inner case : inner){
          //create case...
       }
   }

   public class Inner{
      @InvocableVariable(label='Name')
      public String Name;
   }
}

new XPTO.createRecord(listOfCase); // Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void createRecord(List<Case>) from the type XPTO
```

Comment: What have you tried? What part of it didin't work? Did you get any errors? Please edit your question with more details, and be specific about which part of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: In case it's not perfectly clear in the answer I posted (link is above), to pass in a Collection variable, you must use `List<List<T>>`. There is a link to the documentation for more information.